# Index page loads too slow

Tags: html, web

Here is my new website, I do not understand why the index page takes too long to load, it is just a picture with 2 tables, why is too slow, any work I can do to make it faster?

http://timer.1z.com/

Comment: Its working fine here. may be you net connection or hosting issue will be there

Comment: what is a good hosting site? which of them do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not with your code.  Upgrade your hosting plan or change your hosting provider.

Comment: what is a good hosting site? which of them do you suggest?